# AtomicBoolean to control CPU-intensive tasks in a background service

Tags: android, multithreading, atomic

I use a background service to perform a CPU-intensive task. I want to be able to stop that CPU-intensive task from the client activity without killing the service.

I have defined

```
    public static AtomicBoolean isAborted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
```

together with several other variables/constants shared between the client activity and several background services in a `ScCommon` Class.

In the client activity I have the following code

```
    if (isSolveServiceBound) {
        ScCommon.isAborted.set(true);
    }
```

In the CPU-intensive task of the background service I test and reset this atomicboolean:

```
    if (ScCommon.isAborted.get()) {
        undoAction(false, true);
        ScCommon.isAborted.set(false);
        return;
    }
```

When the atomicboolean is set to `true` after the CPU-intensive task has started, the latter never sees this changed value.

What's wrong with my implementation?

****  EDIT  ****

Here is more detailed code from the main "client" activity:

```
public class ScMain extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {

Handler scMainHandler = new Handler();

. . .


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
. . .
    scMainHandler.post(BackgroundInitialisation);
. . .
}

final Runnable BackgroundInitialisation = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        . . .
        if (intentSolveService == null) {
            intentSolveService = new Intent(mContext, ScSolveService.class);
        }

        if (!isSolveServiceBound) {
            bindService(intentSolveService, solveServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
        . . .
};


public void UndoBtnFired(View view) {
    if (isSolveServiceBusy) {
        if (isSolveServiceBound) {
            ScCommon.isAborted.set(true);
        }

        resetContext(STEP, null);
        return;
    } else {
        undoAction();
    }
}
```

and more code from the background service:

```
    public class ScSolveService extends Service {
    . . .

    public class IncomingHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            isSolveServiceBusy = true;
            msg = message;
            msgArg1 = message.arg1;
            msgWhat = message.what;

            if (message.replyTo != null) {
                mClient = new Messenger(message.replyTo.getBinder());
            }

            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_SOLVE:case MSG_ANALYZE:case MSG_SUGGEST:case MSG_STEP:
                    solve();
                    ScCommon.isSolveServiceBusy = false;
                    break;
                . . .
            }
        }
    }


    public void solve() {
        . . .

        LOOP:
        do {
           . . .
           if ((keepWorking && (isNextStepRequested || isSuggestionRequested)) || isAborted.get()) {
              break LOOP;
           }
           . . .
        } while(isChanged);

        if (isAborted.get()) {
            undoAction(false, true);
            isAborted.set(false);
            return;
        }

        . . .
    }

}
```

Comment: From the limited amount of code you've given, all I can conclude is you've set the boolean to false but there's no check done on the boolean so the Service can't stop.

Comment: @silver2049 The statement with the `ScCommon.isAborted.get()` above is included in the background service loop. The AtomicBoolean is set to "true" in the calling activity.